# Why does cause exist?

Tags: causation

We intuitively believe that everything must have a cause. If that is true, does it mean that causation itelf must have a cause? To be clear, I do NOT mean "does the cause of a cause have a cause?" What I mean
is, what led to causation existing in the first place?

Comment: One option is that the first cause, a.k.a. God, is the cause of itself, causality and the rest, if we follow this line of reasoning, see [cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument). Another option is that the principle only applies to physical events, not abstractions like itself, or that it is just false. That everything has a cause is rather something we *want* to believe, while evidence to the contrary is readily available. It feels discomforting that things can just happen out of the blue, but they do.

Comment: We discussed a similar topic here https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific/72055#72055 TLDR: 'causation' is an explanatory narrative grouping, rather than really existing in the world. It is a useful fiction which the world can contradict at any time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific)

Comment: Also see Stanford Encyclopedia, ["The Metaphysics of Causation"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-metaphysics/).

Comment: You are asking "why": the search for *causes* is exactly the endeavour at answering "why-questions".

Comment: Causation is simply an inherent feature of the natural world. It's existence can be inferred ab initio from the observation of robust correlations, and it's a foundational tenet of all human thinking and behaviour. You would not be able to do anything purposeful if you did not hold at least the prospect of causing a specific effect.

Comment: Not "everything" must havea cause, only "every event", where an event is a change of an instant state.