Is Everything in Time Subject to Cause and Effect?
Is the universe wholly deterministic, with every event in time being a result of a specific cause, or might some events occur independently of prior causes? I’m seeking to understand if cause and effect is the exclusive framework through which time-bound events happen, or if this is a construct of human perception rather than a universal truth.

Can you give an example of something that is not the outcome of a cause? Everything in time/space is the effect of a prior cause.

Pushing Laplace's principle of insufficient cause to its extreme in the spirit of Hume, there's hardly any cause you can gaze at philosophically speaking. Of course colloquially causation occurs throughout time as a chain, but if you conceive time as nothing but a dimension then without a first cause there're only spacetime geometric constraints designated by physics even viewed nondeterminstically...

This question is similar to: Deterministic or stochastic universe?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Not only is this often asked here, the literature in this is also so extensive that chatbots can give good answers. Or look at Wikipedia or SEP

Other than being a duplicate, this is also at risk of being a question for physics, not philosophy

Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63811/is-the-universe-fundamentally-deterministic and other related questions in the physics site

@tkruse This question is completely different; did I mention stochasticism at all? I’m looking at a much wider issue, not just choosing between two options

Then you better reference another question or some source like a book or Wikipedia and describe in your question what you want to know that is not clear in your source.

Causality is only used as informal shorthand in modern physics, which instead uses symmetry & conservation laws at a fundamental level: Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)? https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific/72055#72055 Causality just refers to a mode of storytelling.

There are multiple frameworks for reasoning about events. For most practical purposes of physical reality, cause and effect is the most useful framework to describe reality. This is also used mostly in engineering. For psychological and spiritual purposes, higher abstractions are more useful. For quantum physics and philosophy about the nature of the universe, cause and effect is insufficient, but we don't know enough about indetermninancies to have a good single substitute framework.
Generally and philosophically, it is impossible to prove that any event had no cause, we can only say that we excluded all known possibilities for causes, but that always leaves room for unknown causes.

Thanks for your insights. I agree with most of what you’ve said. However, on the last point, it’s equally challenging to prove the opposite. For instance, one could argue that something has always existed without any cause for its creation.

OP: is cause and effect the exclusive framework through which time-bound events happen, or is this a construct of human perception rather than a universal truth?
The rationality of cause & effect as it appears – not necessarily as it truly is (if it is) – appears to be a construct due to how it breaks down under Kant’s first antinomy, which showed that the world/universe is neither finite nor infinite.
By the way, how spacetime physics may have updated this view is asked here.
Here is the first antinomy, from The Critique of Pure Reason (1781) he laid out the Antinomies of Pure Reason.


1st Antinomy: Thesis: The world is limited with regard to (a) time and
(b) space.
 Proof (a): If the world has no beginning, then for any time t
an infinite series of successive states of things has been synthesized
by t. An infinite series cannot be completed through
successive synthesis. The world has a beginning (is limited
in time). 
 Proof (b): If the world has no spatial limitations, then the
successive synthesis of the parts of an infinite world must be
successively synthesized to completion. The parts of an
infinite world cannot be successively synthesized to completion.
The world is limited with regard to space. 
Antithesis: The world is unlimited with regard to (a) time and (b)
space.
 Proof (a): If the world has a beginning, then the world was
preceded by a time in which the world does not exist, i.e. an empty
time. If time were empty, there would be no sufficient reason
for the world. Anything that begins or comes to be has a
sufficient reason. The world has no beginning. 
 Proof (b): If the world is spatially limited, then it is
located in an infinite space. If the world is located in an
infinite space, then it is related to space. The world cannot
be related to a non-object such as space. The world is not
spatially limited. 

The Stanford Encyclopedia comments, in 4.1 The Mathematical Antinomies:-

we may want to know, as in the first antinomy, whether the world is
finite or infinite. We can seek to show that it is finite by
demonstrating the impossibility of its infinitude. Alternatively, we
may demonstrate the infinitude of the world by showing that it is
impossible that it is finite. This is exactly what the thesis and
antithesis arguments purport to do, respectively. ...
The world is, for Kant, neither finite nor infinite.

From this point Kant turns to that which is comprehensible: the faculty of apperception, mind, the self, and time & space as intuitions.

Thanks for your insights on Kant’s first antinomy, but it’s a bit off-topic from my original question about determinism. it’s very interesting topic to me though. I tend to think the universe is infinite in both time and space.

I don’t think anyone can say for sure what the universe is so that makes it indeterminate for me. Kant’s 1st antimony is just a good example of it. The modern questions are similarly baffling, eg singularities, the clearing, existence.

Also you ask if it’s a construct, so actually I can’t see how my answer is off-topic. ¯\(ツ)/¯

Physically, the causal correlation between eating a big sandwich and getting 1g more of belly fat is impossible to prove scientifically. You don't believe it. Check this out.
Historically, there was a debate about the causal relationship between vaccines and immunity. It is impossible to prove empirically (scientifically) that vaccination causes immunity. Shot 31000 individuals, and you will see an important percentage is not immune. So, strictly, vaccines don't cause immunity.
But what if we just say that "vaccines increase the probabilities of immunity"? That would be good. But now, we have a problem: in what rate? 50% would be fine for me. And for you? Well, when a value is subjective (your tests are different than my tests), that is, when a value can't be objective, it can't be scientific.
In proper terms, causality is a metaphysical mechanism. See Hume: causality is just custom and habit. We learn to relate two facts in time, and we call the first cause and the second, consequence.
So, causality is not scientific. Therefore, the fact that vaccination increases the probability of immunity can't be accepted?
Exactly. But here enters Judea Pearl, that developed mathematical tools that allow establishing formally (that is, objectively, that is, scientifically) the causal relationship between two facts.
See "Causality" from Judea Pearl, for the whole account.

Have you thought much about the physics of losing weight? One consumes energy, converts energy to effort in the brain, metabolism, and muscle action, and one generates heat that radiates to the surroundings. To lose body mass stored as fat we must convert the fat mass into heat that radiates to the surroundings.      The exact mechanisms are unknown or somewhat known. In my experience I add a little more exercise than normal and I go to bed slightly hungry at least 3-4 times per week. That enables me to lose 2 pounds of fat per week in my sleep! I think it radiates away as heat!

@SystemTheory read the book, you are expressing the subjective claims it addresses.

You say :

... if it is a construct of human perception rather than a universal
truth.

Well, it's both.
When examining determinism, in relation to cause and effect, we identify some causes and some effects. The selection of these causes and effects is based on our perceptions: this, as a specific determinate system, is a construct of human perception.
If we get out of the scope of a specific determinate system, and consider the whole universe as a single determinate system, then, in this scope, determinism is a universal truth.

All physical events are both causes and effects. Except perhaps the Big Bang, which supposedly had no cause.
However, the Universe is not deterministic, as causes do not determine their effects with absolute precision. In a probabilistic world the cause determines only the probability distribution of the effect. There is no absolute precision in reality. We are dealing with averages and approximations that are usually accurate enough for most practical purposes.
Besides the Big Bang there are no effects without a cause. But sometimes the cause is not an event. Some living beings with sufficient mental capacity can perform voluntary actions, that are not mere causal reactions to prior events. Voluntary actions are caused by the being's decision to act. Thus, deliberate decisions start new causal chains of causes and effects.

Some neuroscientists mights claim that neural correlates of consciousness could describe precise brain states at the point of a decision, and that a decision is a brain state caused by a prior brain state. Do you have any evidence to show that this is not the case? Maybe you're right, but AFAIK there is no evidence to demonstrate that decisions 'start new causal chains of causes and effects'. Such evidence would be of great interest to professionals in the field. Or have I missed something important in the literature?

Decisions are selections out of multiple alternatives. Causal chains don't have any alternative effects, so the only way to make a selection is to select a new cause.

If you are right, then the next step is to ask whether decisions are real or illusory, not to assume they are real without evidence..

I have no idea what "illusory decision" could possibly mean. A decision made by someone else?

No. An illusory decision would be a mental event we perceive as a decision, but which is the result of a cause and not in any way an exercise of agency or control. We know only of random and causal processes, so to invoke 'causal sui' for mental processes requires justification

How could you perceive something as a decision, if you don't know what a decision is? An illusion is a misinterpretation of an observed event. An interpretation is a selection of the meaning out of multiple alternatives. In other words, experiencing an illusion is a choice.

Why would I not know what a decision is? Not having choices does not necessarily imply a lack of perception.

If no-one ever made a decision, then no-one would know what a decision looks or feels like.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
